# I am facing this error while genearting Pitest report How to solve it

Tags: pitest

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.148 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-26T21:44:44+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.7.2:mutationCoverage (default-cli) on project junit-5-practice: Execution default-cli of goal org.pitest:pitest-maven:1.7.2:mutationCoverage failed: Coverage generation minion exited abnormally!
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
[ERROR] VM : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
[ERROR] Vendor : Private Build
[ERROR] Version : 17.0.7+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.2
[ERROR] Uptime : 4896
[ERROR] Input -> 
[ERROR]  1 : -Dclassworlds.conf=/opt/apache-maven/bin/m2.conf
[ERROR]  2 : -Dmaven.home=/opt/apache-maven
[ERROR]  3 : -Dlibrary.jansi.path=/opt/apache-maven/lib/jansi-native
[ERROR]  4 : -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/kevin/Desktop/JunitPractice/junit-5-practice
[ERROR] BootClassPathSupported : false
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please copy and paste the information and the complete stacktrace below when reporting an issue
[ERROR] VM : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
[ERROR] Vendor : Private Build
[ERROR] Version : 17.0.7+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.2
[ERROR] Uptime : 4897
[ERROR] Input -> 
[ERROR]  1 : -Dclassworlds.conf=/opt/apache-maven/bin/m2.conf
[ERROR]  2 : -Dmaven.home=/opt/apache-maven
[ERROR]  3 : -Dlibrary.jansi.path=/opt/apache-maven/lib/jansi-native
[ERROR]  4 : -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/home/kevin/Desktop/JunitPractice/junit-5-practice
[ERROR] BootClassPathSupported : false
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

How can I solve this error?

I am facing this error while generating a Pitest report. I have successfully run `mvn compile` and then tried to run the cmd to generate the Pitest report.  -->
`mvn test-compile org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your pitest-maven plugin to the latest version (at the moment it is [1.14.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pitest/pitest-maven/1.14.1)) and also use correspondent version [1.2.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.pitest/pitest-junit5-plugin/1.2.0) of pitest-junit5-plugin

See also [Java 8 to Java 17 migration + pitest failing - Mutation testing requires a green suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343517/java-8-to-java-17-migration-pitest-failing-mutation-testing-requires-a-green)