# Facing (Kill ratio is NaN% (0 0)) Issue when running Mutation test pittest in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, java-17, mutation-testing, pitest

Hi we recently migrated from java 11 to java 17 after migration, We are facing following Issue when running MutationTest in Jenkins

**Kill ratio is NaN% (0 0)** when we run in Jenkins

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
<artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
<version>1.11.0</version>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
<artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<configuration>
<argLine>
--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
</argLine> 
</configuration> 
</plugin>
```

dependency We have
used

- Jenkins Plugin - pitmutation:1.0-18
- pitest-maven: 1.11.0
- pitest-junit5-plugin: 1.1.2

We Initially Tried with the following version  but got same issue

- Jenkins Plugin - pitmutation:1.0-18
- pitest-maven: 1.14.2
- pitest-junit5-plugin: 1.2.0

We also Tried with the following version  but got same issue

- Jenkins Plugin - pitmutation:1.0-18
- pitest-maven: 1.13.2
- pitest-junit5-plugin: 1.0.0

but still we got same issue?

In local in target folder i am able to view html file which reports coverage

In Jenkins we are able to get following

```
2023-07-17 14:56:31.635  >> Line Coverage: 858/1021 (84%)
2023-07-17 14:56:31.635  >> Generated 280 mutations Killed 203 (73%)
2023-07-17 14:56:31.635  >> Mutations with no coverage 52. Test strength 89%
2023-07-17 14:56:31.635  >> Ran 251 tests (0.9 tests per mutation)
2023-07-17 14:56:31.635  Enhanced functionality available at https://www.arcmutate.com/
```

but we get Kill ratio is NaN% (0 0) and pit report section no 0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi All issue was with version of Jenkins plugin installed in our jenkins - if you have admin access to the Jenkins you can verify the plugin version installed

https://plugins.jenkins.io/pitmutation/releases/

as you can see the from above link,  Those plugin version (latest 1.0-18) is not compatible with latest pitest-maven:1.14.0

so downgraded  to pitest-maven:1.7.3  and junit5 plugin to 0.15 then it started working refer the snip attached

[image: compatibility]

pom file:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the newer versions of pitest-maven have some tags in the xml that are not supported by the the jenkins plugin.

Following the suggestion from https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-68990  solved the issue for me.

In my case I had a multi module project, so the "fixing" code looks like this:

`find . -iname mutations.xml | xargs sed -i -E -e 's#</?(blocks|indexes)>##g'`

my stack:

- Jenkins Plugin - pitmutation:1.0-18
- pitest-maven: 1.15.8
- pitest-junit5-plugin: 1.2.1

Important thing to notice for anyone who will try to run a mutli module project - there is another problem showing the module names, as described here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-70363